# Mirrored Stacked Column Chart - Javascript / C#?

Tags: c#, javascript, graph, mschart, google-visualization

I am looking for a library to use that will allow me to create mirrored, stacked column charts such as

[image]

For my web application, I am using the Google Visualisations API for interactive client side graphing, and on the server side (for data export), I am using MS Charts.

There are tonnes of Stacked Column Charts out there, but none that seem to allow mirroring.  The closest I have found is [RGraph](http://www.rgraph.net/), but it doesn't seem to be that configurable, so was hoping to have at least more than 1 option.

Ideally I would like a Javascript solution to this, but a good server-side (C#) library would also be ok.

Thanks,
Phil.

Comment: Not configurable? Have you even looked at the Bar chart docs page? There's a demo that does just what you want in the examples folder of the download: examples/bar-income-expenditure.html And the Bar chart docs page is here: https://www.rgraph.net/bar And you can download RGraph here: https://www.rgraph.net/download.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) library for data presentation.  It's a javascript API that creates SVG charts (or VML in IE < 9.0).  I haven't worked with the bar charts personally, but their demo site shows [a chart](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-negative-stack) similar to your link above and I know there are options to invert the axis.  Click "View Options" on the demo site for a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

you can check the `extjs4` chart, it can show combine column chart. [example extjs](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.1.0-gpl/examples/#sample-3)